# Silverstripe: dev/build works on local, but not on external domain

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe project that's working fine on my local. I can run dev/build/?flush=all and the database builds correctly. No errors in the PHP logs or anything. The site is in Dev mode. No problems appearing locally.

I've made a copy of the project and uploaded it to the live/test domain. This is what I have done to move the project to the external domain:

- Compressed the project
- Uploaded & extracted to root directory of domain (i.e. http:// www.project.com/(silverstripe folders like mysite, assets, etc. reside here)/"
- Updated htaccess so the rewrite base is: "/"
- Updated _config file to reflect new MySQL Server, user, pass, and  database.
- Tried to run dev/build/?flush=all but the build stops half way through...

When I say it stops half way through, what I mean is this is the output:

```
Creating database tables
File
Folder
Image
Image_Cached
Group
LoginAttempt
Member
MemberPassword
Permission
PermissionRole
PermissionRoleCode
MemberProfileField
StaffMember
Block
ContentBlock
ContactBlock
GoogleMap
Grid
GridV2
IconTitleText
ImageBanner
ImageSlideshow
InstagramFeed
LatestBlogPosts
Separator
TextHTML
BlockSet
BlogCategory
BlogTag
SiteTree
Page
```

and then it stops...

On my local, the table that builds after "Page" is "MemberProfilePage".

I am guessing this means there's a problem with the "MemberProfilePage" table? However, since there's no errors locally, I have no way of finding out what's causing the problem... that is, until one of you wonderful people points me in the right direction!

Could someone advise the best way to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: 1) Enable error output, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display 2) use a _ss_environment.php for DB settings, see https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/getting_started/environment_management

Comment: Also take a look at your Apache error logs - you may find that the exception/user error that is killing your build is logged there

Comment: @wmk thanks for the reply. Turns out I was declaring an array as though I was writing JS, instead of PHP. Derp. Rookie mistake.

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks for the reply. I checked the apache logs and found the problem. :)

Comment: If it's a "silly mistake" you might delete the question.

Comment: @wmk If other people are experiencing this problem, it could act as a suggestion for something they can try to bug fix the problem. Some beginners (like myself) may not think to check the apache/php logs. It's not doing any harm being here.